# The functional analysis tag

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tagging, tag-wikis

Many elementary questions about functions are given the "[functional-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functional-analysis)" tag. Consider the following examples, all of which are very recent: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1987731/rolles-theorem-and-functions), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1985280/inverse-and-composite-functions), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1974110/one-line-proof-for-a-maximum), [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2000836/absolute-convergence-of-series-f-nxg-nx-implies-convergence-of-series-f), [5](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1998391/conditions-on-exponential-function-with-natural-exponent-in-the-case-of-series-o). This is not a recent phenomena; I've been noticing it for some time.

The confusion is likely incidental. Askers who don't know what functional analysis is are likely to infer that it's simply the "analysis" of "functions".

I believe that [the description of the tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/functional-analysis/info) (i.e., the description that appears when you move your cursor onto the tag) should have some sort of warning.

Comment: There exist also [tag warnings](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21873/do-we-want-tag-warnings-and-for-which-tags/), but I do not think that this issue is serious enough to create also tag warning. Probably [editing the tag-excerpt](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functional-analysis) should be enough.

Comment: Similar confusions abound. The tags [tag:division-algebras] and [tag:functional-equation] spring to mind. Users often try to interpret them with high-school level technology alone, and fail. Educating them is an option (albeit inefficient). Editing the tags is probably the simplest.

Comment: I had forgotten about the possibility of tag warnings. Worth a look, possibly.

Comment: BTW a way of educating users (as @JyrkiLahtonen put it) is to explain either in edit summary or as a comment why the tag was changed. There already [exists a comment template](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates/8587#8587) for functional analysis vs. functional equations. Perhaps similar comment template for functional analysis vs. functions should be added.

Comment: If I had a reputation point for every misplaced functional-analysis tag I've removed....

Comment: @GerryMyerson You do. And then some.

Comment: @Daniel, if I had an *additional* reputation point, etc., etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the number of upvotes on this question it seems that many users agreed with the OP's suggestion. So I have [edited the tag-excerpt](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/49812/revisions) to add the sentence: "For basic questions about functions use more suitable tags like (functions), (functional-equations) or (elementary-set-theory)." Due to the character limit, I had to omit part of the [original tag-excerpt](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/49812/1) created by Willie Wong.

Of course, further improvements to [the tag-info](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/functional-analysis/info) for [functional-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functional-analysis) are more than welcome. (And they may bring you closer to [research assistant badge](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/176/research-assistant).)

Comment: functional-equations has the same problem as functional-analysis, namely, it's a term that has a conventional meaning in advanced mathematics, a meaning that most casual users of this website will not know about. In particular, it's not a good tag for any old question that has an equation with a function in it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson If needed, mention of alternative tags can be added to the [functional-equation tag-excerpt](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/functional-equations/info). We have [a comment template](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates/8587#8587) for functional analysis, similar template can be created for functional equations. And we can make suggestions of tag warnings in [this thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21873/do-we-want-tag-warnings-and-for-which-tags/).

Comment: @GerryMyerson I have added similar sentence to the [functional-equations tag-excerpt](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/87715/revisions). If you see possible further improvements, please do edit it. (Of course, this only helps if the users adding tag actually look at the excerpt.) I did nothing about comment templates and tag warnings for (functional-equations). If you think that template or warning (or both) might be useful, either you or me can post in the relevant threads.